# LOVE2D - How to check how much space the folder the program folder is using

Tags: love2d

I'm making a ComputerCraft emulator and usually there are space limits of about 1MB. I want users to be able to change it and I found out how. Now, I just need to find out how to **actually check** how much space the folder that the program folder is using so I can enforce the space limits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Folders don't have size restrictions and LÖVE doesn't force any restriction in file or folder size. If you want however you can check the size of the file by counting the number of bytes of the file using [File:getSize()](https://love2d.org/wiki/(File):getSize)